How can it be ensured that only the prover can produce a witness for a public circuit in zero-knowledge proofs?
I am very new to the field of zero-knowledge proofs.
Many ZKP protocols build on a problem of complexity class NP to ensure that a solution is verified “quickly” (in poly-time). Often arithmetic or boolean circuits are used for which only the prover has a solution (witness). This is represented by SAT.
Since the circuit is public to both the verifier and the prover, how can it be ensured that only the prover is able to generate a witness from the circuit?
In practice, in Circom there is a witness generator for each arithmetic circuit that finds a solution to it. What prevents the verifier from using a witness generator for a public circuit?

First to say I am also a freshman to ZKP. I guess that if the statement itself is a hard problem, such as "Only Alice knows the pre-image(witness) of a hash value generated by a hash function", then even given the circuit for the statement, nobody else but Alice could product a valid proof.

There are two complementary answers to this question.

The verifier could know a witness, but this does not matter (more precisely, this has no bearing on the zero-knowledge property). Informally, a ZK proof is zero-knowledge if the verifier cannot infer any additional information about the witness by seeing the proof. If the verifier already knows a witness, this is vacuously true. In other words: a prover uses a ZKP when they're afraid that their proof could leak information about the witness. If they're talking to someone who already knows it, there's nothing to be afraid of (but the point of ther ZKP is that it will protect the prover even when the verifier does not already know the witness).

Finding a witness for an arithmetic circuit (e.g. a satisfying assignment for a SAT formula) is a hard problem: the conjecture that it is impossible to do it for every polynomial-size circuits is the $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$ conjecture, probably the most famous and fundamental unsolved problem in theoretical computer science.



In practice, in Circom there is a witness generator for each arithmetic circuit that finds a solution to it.

I don't know Circom, but based on a quick look at it (https://docs.circom.io/), it does not seem to be what it does. But even if it was a tool that finds a witness for a circuit (i.e., a SAT-solver), then it would simply not run in polynomial time for all circuit families unless it solves the $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$ conjecture, and it's quite easy to build tons of concrete circuits on which it will fail. For example, consider the circuit $C(x) = \mathsf{AES}(x) \oplus x$, where $\mathsf{AES}$ refers to the AES block cipher with a fixed (public) random key: any cryptographer would happily bet that your tool won't find a preimage to $y=C(x)$ for a random $x$.
